# How to display the top 50 most viewed items in DSpace statistics

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

When logged in as a site administrator, you can access the statistics page by clicking the Statistics link from the sidebar (Administrative) menu. The page looked like this (From DSpace Demo):

[image]

Based on the image above, all items with 20 or more views are displayed. Is it possible to change this to only display the top 50 (or any arbitrary number) most viewed items regardless whether it has 20 or more views? So instead of **Items Viewed**, I would like to change it to **Top 50 Items Viewed**. Also by default, the list only display the title of the top 10 most viewed items while the rest are just urls. How can I modify that to display the titles of the remaining items?

**UPDATE**

I've discovered that the settings `item.floor` and `item.lookup` in `[dspace]/config/dstat.cfg` are ignored if you changed it from its default values. I submitted this issue in JIRA: [DS-3470](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3470).

With regards to displaying only the top 50 items, this is my xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer.div.items_viewed']/dri:table[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer.table.reportBlock']">
    <table class="ds-table table table-striped table-hover detailtable">
        <xsl:for-each select="dri:row[position() &lt;=51]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using DSpace version 6 (XMLUI) for this instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a quick comment, those numbers are not super reliable since they come from the legacy statistics not the newer Solr-based ones. They are likely to include more bot visits etc than you'd find in the Solr-based usage statistics.

Comment: @schweerelos, thanks for the heads up. If what @benoît-wéry is true that the number of items returned can't be configured, is it possible to limit this using xslt? In the dri, the returned items is within `table id="aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer.table.reportBlock"`. I've searched somewhere how to limit returned rows and one of the solution is to use  `position()` ie `<xsl:for-each select="row/cell/xref[position() < = 50]">`. What do you think? Can this impact on the performance too?

Comment: Limiting in XSL should be an ok workaround if you can't / aren't allowed to change code. Whether your position call works for that, I don't know (I'd have to look at the current XSL for that page and I don't have time, sorry). But I wouldn't worry about performance too much in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out that to reflect the changes made in `dstat.cfg`, all you need to do is to rerun `dspace stat-initial`. With regards to displaying only the top 50 viewed items, I used the code below:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer.div.items_viewed']/dri:table[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer.table.reportBlock']">
    <table class="ds-table table table-striped table-hover detailtable">
        <xsl:for-each select="dri:row[position() &lt;=51]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps anyone who have similar issues. Thanks to Andrea, Terry and Benoît for their answers.

Answer (score 2):

The value of 20 is set here: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/dstat.cfg#L66

I believe the header is set here
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/statistics/ReportGenerator.java#L332

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the amount of items returned by the report can be configured. You may want to take a look a the code, here and next lines: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/269af71afb602808a14edf822ad658c3895e0a37/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/statistics/ReportGenerator.java#L331

The threshold for the amount of views required before an item is considered in that report can indeed be configured in the file Terry mentioned.

As far as I know, the title will be displayed all the time, when available. On demo.dspace.org, the links in your screenshot point to items that do not exist anymore (but that are still present in the SOLR core, I guess). I believe this wouldn't happen on a "real" DSpace, and is only the consequence of the weekly data refresh.

Regards,
Benoît

Comment: No, the title is not always shown -- that number is configurable, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the number of title lookups in `dstat.cfg` (as mentioned by Terry). https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/dstat.cfg#L71

```
# limit the number of lookups of titles and authors to the first X.  Lookup
# invokes the java environment so has quite an impact on performance.
item.lookup=10
```

Comment: I tried this in our production server running dspace 5.5 and another test server running 6.0, it seems this property is not applied even if I changed it to another value (eg 20 and 50). The items returned with titles is still 10. Tried restarting tomcat and clearing the cache from the control panel, it is still returning only 10 items with titles. I'm not sure if this is a bug until someone can confirm this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me to be honest! Have you checked whether it's a known bug in Jira? https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS

Comment: Didn't find this issue in Jira, also the property `item.floor` is also ignored if changed from its original value. I will report this in Jira. Thanks.